# I want to remove decline option based on recipients in docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending an Envelope to multiple recipients with routing order.

For example, aaa@gmail.com with routing order 1 and bbb@gmail.com routing order 2.

Here I would like to remove decline option bbb@gmail.com.

I saw that we can do it from branding configuration. But it will remove the decline button for all the recipients.

Docusign DevZone can help me out of this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to remove the "Decline" button at the recipient level.  (I don't see a property for that on the **Signer** Recipient Type in the [API documentation](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf).)